# Minimum of a function.

Tags: maxima-minima

Determine the minimum value of the expression
$$x^2+y^2+5z^2-xy-3yz-xz+3x-4y+7z$$ 
where x , y and z are real numbers.

My Solution :
Let $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+5z^2-xy-3yz-xz+3x-4y+7z$

I calculated the partial derivative equations as :
$\frac{df}{dx}=2x-y-z+3=0$
$\frac{df}{dy}=2y-x-3z-4=0$
$\frac{df}{dz}=10z-3y-x+7=0$

Solving above equations, I got $x=-4$,$y=-3$,$z=-2$

Then calculating further partial derivatives, I got:

$A=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=2$
$B=\frac{d^2f}{dy^2}=2$
$C=\frac{d^2f}{dz^2}=10$
$F=\frac{d^2f}{dydz}=-3$
$G=\frac{d^2f}{dxdz}=-1$
$H=\frac{d^2f}{dxdy}=-1$

Now, matrices :

$$A_{1} = \begin{vmatrix}
A & H \\
H & B
\end{vmatrix} = 3$$

$$A_{2} = \begin{vmatrix}
A & H & G \\
H & B & F \\
G & F & C
\end{vmatrix} = 4$$

$A$, $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are positive.
So, $f(x,y,z)$ is minimum at $x=-4$,$y=-3$,$z=-2$.

So, $f(x,y,z)$ at $x=-4$,$y=-3$,$z=-2$   => $f(x,y,z)=-7$.

Answer :   -7.

Is this solution correct?   Please advise.

Comment: Please use MathJax to make the question more easily readable. In particular, I really don't understand what you're saying in the matrix part.

Comment: @MattiP.   ...   I tried using MathJax,   but unfortunately, it's not working on my PC for some reason.

Comment: Try at least putting dollar signs around the first equation and update the post. See what happens ....

Comment: There will only be one extremum so to show your solution is a minimum evaluate $f$ somewhere else and if it is larger than -7 you have a minimum. Recommend looking at $x=y=z=0$

Comment: @user121049   ...thanks for the suggestion. I am getting all values of f(x,y,z) as more than -7;   for x=-4,y=-3,z=-2.   Please advise if my solution is accurate.   Thanks.